# Mule 4 issue while using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, mule, dataweave, mule-esb

I am using the below xpath expression to extract the String, its not working as expected anyone please help me out here

**XPATH Exp:**

```
XmlModule::xpath('/*:ExecuteXMLStringResponse/*:ExecuteXMLStringResult',payload.^raw,{})]"
```

**Payload:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExecuteXMLStringResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<ExecuteXMLStringResult>
&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;&lt;DCResponse&gt;&lt;Status&gt;Success&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;Authentication&gt;&lt;Status&gt;FirstTimeLogIn&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;Token&gt;646d9300-7341-41a0-9c0f-05a40c3f2b94&lt;/Token&gt;&lt;/Authentication&gt;&lt;ResponseInfo&gt;&lt;ApplicationId&gt;23429782&lt;/ApplicationId&gt;&lt;SolutionSetInstanceId&gt;b08cc093-c735-4435-b7b9-beef1c10dd23&lt;/SolutionSetInstanceId&gt;&lt;CurrentQueue&gt;&lt;/CurrentQueue&gt;&lt;/ResponseInfo&gt;&lt;ContextData&gt;&lt;Field key="RiskClass"&gt;C&lt;/Field&gt;&lt;/ContextData&gt;&lt;/DCResponse&gt;</ExecuteXMLStringResult></ExecuteXMLStringResponse>
```

**I am getting:**

'¬í ava.util.ArrayListx �Ò ™ Ça � '

The above arraylist has to be converted into the required format.

**Expected Output:**

The whole String(As mentioned below) inside the  tag

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;&lt;DCResponse&gt;&lt;Status&gt;Success&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;Authentication&gt;&lt;Status&gt;FirstTimeLogIn&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;Token&gt;646d9300-7341-41a0-9c0f-05a40c3f2b94&lt;/Token&gt;&lt;/Authentication&gt;&lt;ResponseInfo&gt;&lt;ApplicationId&gt;23429782&lt;/ApplicationId&gt;&lt;SolutionSetInstanceId&gt;b08cc093-c735-4435-b7b9-beef1c10dd23&lt;/SolutionSetInstanceId&gt;&lt;CurrentQueue&gt;&lt;/CurrentQueue&gt;&lt;/ResponseInfo&gt;&lt;ContextData&gt;&lt;Field key="RiskClass"&gt;C&lt;/Field&gt;&lt;/ContextData&gt;&lt;/DCResponse&gt;
```

Please help me in finding out the required output.

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still need to add further information for your question to become solvable.

Comment: Thank you...I have edited and updated back.....

Comment: I think there is no prefix (namespaces) in element name so you can update it like: `'//ExecuteXMLStringResponse/ExecuteXMLStringResult'` and use double `/` first. if not run again then check with default namespace declaration.

Comment: Thanks Amarendra. I am getting string as a form of array list after using the given solution                                                                                                 '¬í  ava.util.ArrayListx �Ò ™ Ça � '  ..............How to convert this array-list into the required value....

Comment: Why not directly `output application/java --- payload.ExecuteXMLStringResponse. ExecuteXMLStringResult`

Answer (score 3):

Hi I would recommend to use directly dataweave instead of XPath.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java 
--- 
payload.ExecuteXMLStringResponse.ExecuteXMLStringResult
```